# How to make Hover Loop with background-image in CSS

Tags: css

I want to make an special Hover effect loop in the website full width header.

I have 8 Columns with text modules in the Header and column 1 have background image. so i want the background image fade out in the header and cover all other columns with background-image.

How to do it?
The CSS snippet and HTML code is Copied from the answer to make it easy to understand the main point of the question with details.

[The example of what I want to achieve](https://www.extyl-pro.ru)

```css
#main-row {
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
}


.et_pb_column {
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
}

.et_pb_module {
width:calc(100% - 30px);
padding:0 14px;
border:1px solid black;
background:pink;
position:relative;
  z-index:10;
  height:50px;
}

.wrapper-background {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:0;
  transition: background 3s;
}

#main-row:hover .et_pb_module {
  background:none;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_module:hover {
  background:red;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_0 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_0:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:cyan;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_0 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_1:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:lightblue;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_1 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_2:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:darkgray;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_1 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_3:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:blue;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_2 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_4:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:gray;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_2 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_5:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:green;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_3 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_6:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:yellow;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_3 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_7:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:orange;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="main-row" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0 main-row et_pb_row_4col">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_0    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_0 column-1 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_text -->
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_1 column-2 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
 
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_1    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_2 column-3 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
   </div> 
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_3 column-4 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">

   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
      <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_2    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_4 column-5 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_5 column-6 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_3    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_6 column-7 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7 column-8 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
    
    
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 animation. [CSS animation docs](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) Main things: your main row must have transparent background. Must have background-image property, but with image contains only transparent layer, without it, it won't work. Plus you must have the same html architecture.

```css
#main-row {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
}

[class^="et_pb_column_"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.et_pb_column_1 {
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
}

.et_pb_column_2 {
    top: 8px;
    left: 125px;
}

.et_pb_column_3 {
    top: 8px;
    left: 242px;
}

.et_pb_column_4 {
    top: 8px;
    left: 359px;
}

.et_pb_column_5 {
    top: 125px;
    left: 8px;
}

.et_pb_column_6 {
    top: 125px;
    left: 125px;
}

.et_pb_column_7 {
    top: 125px;
    left: 242px;
}

.et_pb_column_8 {
    top: 125px;
    left: 359px;
}

.et_pb_column_1:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-1;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_2:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_3:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-3;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_4:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-4;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_5:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-5;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_6:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-6;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_7:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-7;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.et_pb_column_8:hover ~ #main-row {
  -webkit-animation-name: background-col-8;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes background-col-1 {
    0% {
        background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
        background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes background-col-2 {
    0% {
         background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
         background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes background-col-3 {
    0% {
         background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
         background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes background-col-4 {
    0% {
         background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
         background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes background-col-5 {
    0% {
        background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
        background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes background-col-6 {
    0% {
         background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
         background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes background-col-7 {
    0% {
         background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
         background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes background-col-8 {
    0% {
         background: url('https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/asfalt-light.png');
    }
    100% {
         background: url('http://www.permstore.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/mphderbglg_01.jpg');
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="main-section" class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 et_section_regular">
    <div class="et_pb_column_1"><p> SOME TEXT </p></div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_2">Your content goes here. Edit or remove this text inline or in the module Content settings.</div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_3"><p> SOME TEXT </p></div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_4">Your content goes here. Edit or remove this text inline or in the module Content settings.</div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_5"><p> SOME TEXT </p></div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_6"><p> SOME TEXT </p></div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_7">Your content goes here. Edit or remove this text inline or in the module Content settings.</div>
    <div class="et_pb_column_8"><p> SOME TEXT </p></div>

    <div id="main-row" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0 et_pb_row_4col"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183462/discussion-on-answer-by-irina-kovalchuk-how-to-make-hover-loop-with-background-i).

Answer (score 0):

In css, you cannot change a parent property from one of its child.

But you can create a child elemnt with the dimensions of the wrapper and update the background when the mouse is hover it.

In the example below, dimensions, transitions and even background colors can be adjusted.

```css
.wrapper {
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  padding:0 14px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(25% - 30px);
  height:50px;
  background:pink;
  z-index:10;
}

.wrapper-background {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index :0;
  transition: background 3s;
}

.wrapper:hover .col-xs-3 {
  background:none;
}
.wrapper:hover .col-xs-3:hover {
  background:red;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(1):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:blue;
  z-index:0;
}

.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(3):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:darkgray;
  z-index:0;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(5):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:yellow;
  z-index:0;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(1) .col-xs-3:nth-child(7):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:orange;
  z-index:0;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(1):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:gray;
  z-index:0;
}

.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(3):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:black;
  z-index:0;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(5):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:green;
  z-index:0;
}
.wrapper:hover .row:nth-child(2) .col-xs-3:nth-child(7):hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:lightblue;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adapted to your html, ids and class :
You need to add a  after each et_pb_module

```css
#main-row {
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
}


.et_pb_column {
  display:inline-block;
  width:25%;
}

.et_pb_module {
width:calc(100% - 30px);
padding:0 14px;
border:1px solid black;
background:pink;
position:relative;
  z-index:10;
  height:50px;
}

.wrapper-background {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:0;
  transition: background 3s;
}

#main-row:hover .et_pb_module {
  background:none;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_module:hover {
  background:red;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_0 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_0:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:cyan;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_0 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_1:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:lightblue;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_1 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_2:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:darkgray;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_1 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_3:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:blue;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_2 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_4:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:gray;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_2 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_5:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:green;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_3 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_6:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:yellow;
  z-index:0;
}
#main-row:hover .et_pb_column_3 .et_pb_module.et_pb_text_7:hover ~ .wrapper-background {
  background:orange;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-row" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0 main-row et_pb_row_4col">
    <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_0    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_0 column-1 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_text -->
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_1 column-2 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
 
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_1    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_2 column-3 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
   </div> 
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_3 column-4 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">

   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
      <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_2    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_4 column-5 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_5 column-6 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column --><div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_4 et_pb_column_3    et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
    
    
    <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_6 column-7 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
      <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7 column-8 et_hover_enabled et_pb_bg_layout_light  et_pb_text_align_left">
    
    
    
   </div>
      <div class="wrapper-background"></div>
   </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
    
    
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much AllirionX i will test it )

Comment: AllirionX Float with display:inline-block; is not sopported.

Comment: I edited the float property as it was useless, but that's not the important part I guess. The idea is to display a fake background under all the .col-xs-6 div, depending on which .col-xs-6 div you hover.
When you hover, the .col-xs-6 divs' background is removed, and the next .wrapper-background is displayed. It allows you, for each block to set a different background-color or image in the .wrapper-background. 
It should work with more than 2 columns and rows.

Comment: Yes i agree, did you check the example at >>> www.extyl-pro.ru  ?
I am dreaming this kind of Header for my new Project. It has auto loop too and background multiple slides with every column.

Comment: still not working, can you make it again with the exact IDS of my code? so i will make sure to test that i am not doing anything on wrong way

Comment: Just edited to make sure it matches the www.extyl-pro.ru display. I added a few columns and even a red background on "active" div. I don't see your html code (only your css), it makes it difficult to adapt this to your ids and classes. By the way, why not using some javascript to do this trick ? Just change the bakcground properties and the way I select the next .wrapper-background should be improved (but the demo works).

Comment: i am Using Wordpress with divi theme and i don't have html file because divi theme has module to insert code in HTML.

Comment: i can only access html codes through php. you know it better about Wordpress.

Comment: Edited my answer again : you will  need to update your html code though and add a <div class="wrapper-background"></div> after each ".et_pb_column" div. If you cannot update the html code, then I am out of option. Also, positioning properties in the css are quite important, don't remove position:relative and z-index properties.

Comment: AllirionX i have tried but not working, i think i am editing HTML structure on wrong way.
With java script this is easy to achieve?

Comment: Hey, the second code snippet above works for you right ? Do you have the real URL where I could test it ? There may be some external styling that prevent it from working.

Comment: Yes this is the active url with active Code: when hover then every Column turns white. .permstore.com/practice-code/

Comment: The <div class="wrapper-background"></div> are missing from the html. And there is some css messing with the results : .et_pb_column {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;} should be .et_pb_column {
    float: left;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;}

Comment: how to add this class to html? i have no idea

Comment: I don't know how you can edit the html of the divi theme in wordpress, but I guess you have to find where the <div class="et_pb_module..."> are added in your theme and add the <div class="wrapper-background"></div> afterwards.

Comment: <div class="et_pb_module..."> i think it should be in the one of .php file because divi theme has no special HTML file. i see many html codes in php files

Comment: i search in all wordpress files in Editor mode. nothing i have found.

Comment: but i found  .et_pb_module  in the list where all the styles are written together without <dive> markup

Comment: AllirionX i have done it, Your code is working  but only in 2  columns.

Comment: everything is working now. Thank you for your Help. I really Appreciated )

Comment: But now i have only Rows. How to Convert in Normal form?
 li:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
   this formula is correct?

Comment: Can you provide a test URL so I can see what is your issue ?

Comment: Now everything working fine. But only i want to add the Automatic slide Transition same as on origional >> www.extyl-pro.ru

The link to be tested is www.permstore.com

Comment: i want to make it with java from the scratch.

Comment: Can you code only 4 blocks in 2 rows with all animations and every block must have hover effect and at least 2 automatic background animations and the progress line for every animation ?  i will understand the code and will write other code by myself for other blocks. I will use CSS hacks if needed

Comment: Please sir you will definately help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343817/how-to-add-simple-progress-bar-and-how-to-link-with-the-background-function